# gnuplot plot xy cspline with data points in order

Tags: time-series, gnuplot, smoothing

Here is a minimum example:

```
set xrange [31:42]
set yrange [3.5:6.5]
set nokey

plot "-" using 2:3 smooth cspline
2015 34 4       
2016 41 5       
2017 40 6       
2018 32 6
```

The result looks nice but ignores the time series:

[image: the result looks nice but ignores the time series]

minimal example using splot instead of plot:

```
set view map
splot "-" using 2:3:1 with line
2015    34  4       
2016    41  5       
2017    40  6       
2018    32  6
```

The result is correct but does not look nice:
[image: result is correct but does not look nice]

How can I smooth this as in the first example?

Comment: All smooth options of the gnuplot plot command first make the data monotonic in dimension x.

Comment: Since the result is a graphic in a LaTeX2e document there is a hack solution:  generate this one curve in tiktz and patch it onto the graphic.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:  Make gnuplot output a complex graph without this troublesome non-monotonic curve to a LaTeX2e picture, draw this curve separately using the LaTeX2e TikZ package, and edit the picture to include the curve in the correct position and scale.

\addplot[smooth] coordinates {

(34,4)
(41,5)
(40,6)
(32,6)

}